# Java Hibernate creates db table with Varchar(255), how to increase to Varchar(1000)?

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I want to increase the 255 to 1000 when the table is automatically created by Java Hibernate, but how to do this?

Part of the code that might need changes for it:

```
@Entity
public class Work implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue

    private long workNumber;
    private int fromYear;
    private int tillYear;
    private String name;
    private String profession;
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    public Work() {
    }

    public Work(long workNumber, int fromYear, int tillYear, String name, String profession, String description) {
        this.setWorkNumber(workNumber);
        this.setFromYear(fromYear);
        this.setTillYear(tillYear);
        this.setName(name);
        this.setProfession(profession);
        this.setDescription(description);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not trying simply

`@Column(columnDefinition="varchar(1000)")`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to explicitly specify in the annotation, for example for the profession attribute your code would look like

```
@Column(length=1000)
private String profession;
```

The same principle applies if you want for example to have a different name for your property in your object than the name of the column in database, you override the convention with some configuration.

Comment: I tried this, but the datatype changed from varchar(255) to TEXT, is that normal?

Comment: try this: @Column(length=1000, columndefinition="varchar")

Comment: Depends on your database which one are you using?

Comment: @FredericClose That doesn't work, my code doesn't even run now

Comment: @AlanHay I just want it to be varchar 1000

Answer (score 1):

You add a @Column annotation to the property and set a length property on it: Very, very basic JPA stuff. You would do well to read at least the Java EE 6 tutorial on the subject to learn about the basic annotations that you have available.