# DataIntegrityViolationException during tests ("Value too long for column") with H2

Tags: java, spring, jpa, h2

I'm simply using a `JpaRepository` to save objects on a database. A new (quite long) field was added and now some tests are failing with

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; 
    SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
    at com.Tests.test(Tests.java:43)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
    at com.Tests.test(Tests.java:43)
  Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: 
  Value too long for column "PAYMENT_TEMPLATES VARCHAR(255)": "... (338)"; SQL statement:
```

There are no issues in the actual database, but on H2 the default limit for varchars is 255 characters. Is there a way to set it only in test classes/configuration, instead of explicitly using the `@Column` annotation, like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19906721/java-hibernate-creates-db-table-with-varchar255-how-to-increase-to-varchar10)?

Comment: You can use an ORM.xml file with the column value set, and configure your test setup to use that in the persistence unit. Alternatively, you can use a specific SQL script instead (JPA can generate DDL scripts as well as run them), and so can tweak any values yourself.